# PHP SQLITE LOADING LAG

Tags: php, sqlite, lag

[image]This code causes a massive lag while being executed.without this bit it takes 0.78secs.with the code it takes 6.87 secs.Is there anybody out there who can pin point the lag code and provide me with a solution to eliminate this lag. Your help is greatly appreciated.

code

```
    <?php 
$row=0;
while ($r=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $row++;

  foreach($r as $k => $v) { ${$k} = $v; } // get all columns as variables

  //print a table row
  $sql="SELECT items.id i_id, status,manufacturerid,model,label,cpuno,corespercpu from items,item2soft ".
       " where item2soft.itemid=items.id  AND item2soft.softid={$r['id']}";

  $sthi=db_execute($dbh,$sql);
  $ri=$sthi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $nitems=count($ri);
  $institems="";
  $licitems=0;

  for ($i=0;$i<$nitems;$i++) {
    $rstatus=(int)$ri[$i]['status'];
    if ($rstatus==1) { $attr="style='background-color:green;font-weight:bold;color:#efefef' title='Status: Stored'"; }
    elseif ($rstatus==2) { $attr="style='background-color:red;font-weight:bold;' title='Status: Defective'"; }
    elseif ($rstatus==3) { $attr="style='background-color:#cecece;font-weight:bold;' title='Status: Obsolete'"; }
    else { $attr=" title='Status: In Use' "; }

    $x=($i+1).": <span $attr >({$ri[$i]['label']}) </span>".$agents2[$ri[$i]['manufacturerid']]['title']." ".$ri[$i]['model'];

    if ($i%2) $bcolor="#D9E3F6";
    //if ($i%2) $bcolor="#ECF1FB";
    else $bcolor="#ffffff";
    $institems.="<div style='margin:0;padding:0;background-color:$bcolor'>".
                "<a href='$scriptname?action=edititem&amp;id={$ri[$i]['i_id']}'>$x</a></div>";

    if (empty($lictype) || $lictype==0) { $licitems++; } //per box
    elseif ($lictype==1) { $licitems+=$ri[$i]['cpuno']; } //per cpu
    elseif ($lictype==2) { $licitems+=$ri[$i]['cpuno']*$ri[$i]['corespercpu']; } //per core
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Lag from what? running the query? Dumping out 6 kajillion rows of data? Or perhaps the horrible version of `extract()` you're running for EVERY query? You shouldn't be polluting your variable namespace like that.

Comment: Hi Marc thanks for your reply i have not more than 3000 records in my table.Its most definitely is the query.but how would I eliminate this problem.

Comment: Not use it in a loop?

Comment: You're running a sub-query based on the results of some other query. That means you're running 3000+1 queries, just to execute this code. Rewrite as a SINGLE `join`ed query. And since you're embedding external data in that subquery, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well, even if it's just a simple numeric ID number.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice. Did you write a procedural wrapper for PDO?

Comment: I'll try a JOIN query.Thanks Marc.

Comment: Hi Marc I've tried a JOIN it only make things worse. Maybe the my join is not effective.any ideas

Comment: Hi RainFromHeaven thanks for your reply. I'm not sure the PDO.do you see something wrong with it?